# SQL query to obtain rows around a specific row

Tags: sql

I have table structure for competition:

```
user_id | score
```

and I need get information 2 rows before (for example) user_id=20 and 2 rows after for show rank table.

I want this result of score table:

```
order | user_id | score
   23 | XY1     |   240
   24 | XY1     |   247
   25 | 20      |   250 (my specific row)
   26 | XY1     |   252
   27 | XY1     |   290
```

Comment: Relational databases generally don't provide guarantees about order unless you specify it. Your table will need some column to specify the piece of data you want to order by. That could be a timestamp or surrogate key if you want insertion order.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? In Postgres or Oracle you can use `lead()` and `lag()` function to access the next or previous row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with aaa as
(
SELECT  
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY score ) AS 'ROW_NUMBER', score, user_id
)

select * from aaa where ROW_NUMBER between
(select ROW_NUMBER-2 from aaa where user_id = 25) AND
(select ROW_NUMBER+2 from aaa where user_id = 25)
```

Comment: WITH clause isn't for MySQL. Can you rewrite example on MySQL syntax? Thanks